# STL algorithms return type cast without possible data loss

Tags: c++, stl, type-conversion

I am trying to create a template function that returns the result of a STL algorithm function without any "possible data loss" warning.

```
template<typename T>
T sum(vector<T> A) {
     return accumulate(A.begin(), A.end(), 0);
}

int main() {
    vector<float> A;
    sum(A);

    return 0;
}
```

but this gives me:
Warning C4244   'return': conversion from '_Ty' to 'T', possible loss of data
Warning C4244   '=': conversion from 'float' to '_Ty', possible loss of data

I also tried static cast but I still get the second warning ('float' to '_Ty').

```
 template<typename T>
 T sum(vector<T> A) {
      return static_cast<T>(accumulate(A.begin(), A.end(), 0));
 }
```

IS there a way to eliminate this type of warnings?

Comment: `accumulate(A.begin(), A.end(), T{});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a vector of float's, so desired return type of `accumulate` should be also `float`. Now it is `int`, because such type was deduced based on third passed parameter of `accumulate` - type of `0` numeric literal is `int`.

To solve this problem, you should pass `value_type` of vector as `float` with default initialization (to zero) by `T{}`:

```
accumulate(A.begin(), A.end(), T{});
```

Comment: T{} is not default initialisation. It is value initialisation.